# How to get html source code from external url

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get html source code from an external web page?

Something like: `getHtml('http://google.com');`.

I've tried to get content of iframe using: `$("#frame").contents().find("html");`, but if in my case the webpage doesn't have html tags, just 1 line of text. I can't do it with php `file_get_contents()` because it doesn't keep session data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get html code using javascript with a url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375461/get-html-code-using-javascript-with-a-url)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cross domain? not possible without a server process. If you are on windows and can use HTA you can use the iframe

Answer (score 2):

With javascript, getting the file contents from another domain is not allowed in many browsers for security reasons. In php, you'd have to utilize [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

For a workaround, you can make a php script with curl on your local domain and call that with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using JavaScript and XMLHttpRequest with `setRequestHeader('content-type','xml/text')` and the page that you want to scrape will return the responseText as the html of the page.

Comment: This answer looks incorrect. You can delete it if you like. This might be a good idea because I think you now have less than one reputation which is not good. If you delete this it might go back to one.