# Parsing HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, css, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

There is a site I'm trying to parse. I want to get "stars-icons" from there. Here it is (for example):

https://sbis.ru/contragents/contragentcard/6671281463/667101001
I do it like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"https://sbis.ru/contragents/contragentcard/6671281463/667101001");
request.KeepAlive = true; request.Timeout = 5000;
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.107 Safari/537.36";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, @";q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, @"gzip, deflate");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
respText = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

But I'm getting just HTML-code which doesn't have the necessary data. Using Google Chrome F12 option I can see that "star" has such code:

```
<div class="icon-16 icon-Favourite icon-done" style="padding-right: 8px;"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="icon-16 icon-Favourite icon-disabled" style="padding-right: 8px; color: #eeeeee!important;"></div>
```

That's what I'm trying to define. But I'm not getting this in the code using HttpWebRequest. How can I do that? How can I do that at least anyway? Thank's in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot get cross-site content in javascript like that. You'll need an ajax function, possible solution here: [Get contents of link tag with javascript - not CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708387/get-contents-of-link-tag-with-javascript-not-css/18447625#18447625)