# How can I get value from jSON using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parsing, jsonp

How can I parse "h" value from the following jSON using javascript?

**JSON Content:**

```
info = { "title" : "Laura Branigan - Self Control", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/p8-pP4VboBk/default.jpg", "length" : "5", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "http://ping.aclst.com/ping.php/2452159/p8-pP4VboBk?h=761944", "h" : "83135b0b3cf927b5e6caf1cf991b66b3" };
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it looks like you should read some tutorials on AJAX, and possibly try and write a few hello worlds before you tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh! Now I understand your question.
You don't know how to get the response from a url into a javascript variable.
You need a small ajax script for this:

```
var youTubeUrl = "http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=p8-pP4VboBk";

var request = makeHttpObject();
request.open("GET", youTubeUrl, true);
request.send(null);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState == 4){
    eval(request.responseText);//this should create the info variable.
    alert(info.h); //<<<---this should be it!
    //TODO: add your code to handle the info.h here.
    }
};

function makeHttpObject() {
  try {return new XMLHttpRequest();}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}
  try {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
  catch (error) {}

  throw new Error("Could not create HTTP request object.");
}
```

Code mostly copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6375580/1311434

Note that I haven't tested this code, but I hope it get's you in the right direction.
Be sure that you can trust the code you retrieve from the original URL as it's a bit dangerous to eval() code you retrieve from another site.

Comment: Browser (Chrome) give the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. How can i solve this?

Comment: start chrome with "[path-to-chrome]\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security

Comment: i tried, but problem is same

Comment: Strange, it works for me...
This is my path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security

Comment: This is my test file:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5789615

Comment: ok, i saw the alert window but its empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I think it is simpler

```
info.h
```

Comment: yes is working but how can i get this value from the external url?

Comment: I can´t access this url by ajax. I'm receiving this error from console: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=p8-pP4VboBk"

Can´t you access this parameter directly from youtube site? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

The string you have above is a complete JavaScript object, You can think of this as a hash table or an associative key array where `"key":"value"` if you want to index into this array or object you simply use it key thus `Object['key']` where key can be an int or a string or any object

Answer (score 0):

Json objects are perfectly integrated in javascript.

This means that for a definition:

```
var myObject = { "name": "Doe", "parents": {"father": "Louis", "mother": "Ophelia"}};
```

You can simply access the data with following statements:

```
var myName = myObject.name;
var myFather = myObject.parents.father;
var myMother = myObject.parents.mother;
```

It really is as simple as that.

As an exact answer to your question, it is indeed `info.h`.

UPDATE:
If you mean the h from the `info.pf` url, that would be

```
var h = info.pf.substr(info.pf.indexOf("?h=")+3, 999);
```