# how to convert this json data in php

Tags: php, api, json

I am using an api which is giving me a very strange json format.. i'm posting its data which i am getting thru it..

```
info = { "title" : "Asian Dad: B Again!? (you die)", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/IN7o2Iy89WQ/default.jpg", "length" : "2", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "f53762dab34022e9d851ab71e0bf166f" };
```

I'm trying to print this data in php but i'm not able to do that..nothing is showing on my webpage,....
My code are..

First i tried,

```
<?php
$url="http://www.website-name.com/a/itemInfo/?video_id=IN7o2Iy89WQ&ac=www";
$info=file_get_contents($url);
$info=json_decode($info,true);
echo $info;
?>
```

My second attempt was,

```
<?php
$url="http://www.website-name.com/a/itemInfo/?video_id=IN7o2Iy89WQ&ac=www";
$info=file_get_contents($url);
$info=json_decode($info,true);
$info->h;
?>
```

My last attempt was,

```
<?php
$url="http://www.website-name.com/a/itemInfo/?video_id=IN7o2Iy89WQ&ac=www";
$info=file_get_contents($url);
$info=json_decode($info,true);
$info['h'];
?>
```

Nothing is happening..

please somebody help me

API Url converted...

Comment: `$url="http://www.website-name.com/itemInfo/?video_id=IN7o2Iy89WQ&ac=www";`   IS this sending a JSON? Are you sure?

Comment: Can you `var_dump($info);` after your second and third line and show us the output?

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri plaese check now..

Comment: @TheWolf ...my webpage is showing NULL if i use var_dump($info);

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126303/how-can-i-get-h-value-from-the-link-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The page is sending 
`"info = { "title" : "Asian Dad: B Again!? (you die)", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/IN7o2Iy89WQ/default.jpg", "length" : "2", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "058ce93db26fce4a9f1cb41ae2e7c1bb" };"`

You cannot use json_decode on this because the `info =` and the `;` at the end are not json. You have to strip the `info =` and the `;`.

```
   $url="http://www.website-name.com/a/itemInfo/?video_id=IN7o2Iy89WQ&ac=www";
   $info = file_get_contents($url);
   $info = trim($info, "info = ");
   $info = rtrim($info, ";");
   $json = json_decode($info, true);
   echo $json['status'];
```

Comment: getting error...Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/lpmqcrax/public_html/download/info.php on line 8

Comment: @Kapil Sorry, missing the second argument to json_decode. It works now :-)

Comment: but it is not working properly...I want to print $json['h'] value which is f53762dab34022e9d851ab71e0bf166f but it is giving me 0cedafe839fc2337f52355ba959576bb which is unfair...do you why is that happening ?

Comment: it is giving all the information correct except the "h" value..for which i'm doing all of this..any way to get the right value.

Comment: @Kapil To get the right value, you have to fix the server code.

Comment: @kapil the 'h' value is different in all of our sample data! It's probably a hash or access token cookie value...

Comment: @Nico yes you are right...it is access token..i need this value to generate mp3 file

Answer (score 1):

The data I got from the URL in your example is

```
info = { "title" : "Asian Dad: B Again!? (you die)", "image" : "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/IN7o2Iy89WQ/default.jpg", "length" : "2", "status" : "serving", "progress_speed" : "", "progress" : "", "ads" : "", "pf" : "", "h" : "5cddd4d1667f24aa9a0f5a6cc21e24e3" };
```

That's an executable JavaScript snippet, not actually JSON. The reason your php is failing is due to the 'info =' part... json_encode returns null on decoding failure.

While this is an assignment of a variable to a JavaScript object, that would work as JSON too if you removed the 'info =' and semicolon. Assuming the responses are predictable, you could do this with php str_replace, but finding  an API that returns JSON for your source would be a more reliable and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `NULL` when you `var_dump($info)` on the second line as you mentioned in comments, then `file_get_contents()` doesn't retrieve the data.

It's most likely because `allow_url_fopen` is set to false in PHP.ini

Comment: getting error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/lpmqcrax/public_html/download/info.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

From the [`json_decode()` documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

> Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

If 2nd parameter is set to true it returns an array !

SO your first and second attempt is wrong.! It should work third attempt. Just check if you retrieve the data.