# Parse html page from url link with xPath(javascript, jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, xpath, parse-cloud-code

I'm really new to Javascript/jQuery. I've coded in Objective-C and Swift before and there it was possible to parse a (x)html-website with XPath and a framework like Hpple.

Now I have to do something like that in JavaScript(Cloud Code from parse.com).

My problem is now, that I'd like to parse like that:

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
var xpath = "//body";
someJavaScriptMagic.parse(url, xpath);
```

I've often seen people using the `document.evaluate`method, but there they parsed the website on which they were at the moment and not another website.

Is there a way to do that?

I dont know if it's important, but I'm using CloudCode from parse.com

EDIT:

I've already tried using the ajax-query:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'http://www.digitec.ch', success: function(data) { alert(data); } });
```

But I get the following error each time:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.digitec.ch/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: You want to fetch the website's HTML code from the given URL and then extract elements from that HTML code?

Comment: Does it *have* to be XPath?

Comment: If you know an other way where I can use a "parse-String" feel free to show. :)

Comment: you NEED to use YQL to do this from JavaScript. it accepts urls, and xpath expressions, and gives you back xml with cors or json that your js can consume.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make AJAX requests (i.e., HTTP requests in JavaScript) to a different domain from the domain that served the resource making the request. In other words, if your JavaScript is served from "foo.com/some.js", and it is attempting to fetch "google.com", it will fail. This is called the Same-origin policy, and it is a fundamental principle in web application security. Read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. Googling "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" (from your error) will give you much more information about this as well.

You can work around this by making a request to a script on your own domain that serves as a proxy. For example:

**foo.com/some.js**

```
var url = "http://www.google.com";
someJavaScriptMagic.get("foo.com/fetchUrl?url="+url);
```

Then you had a  backend script that accepts that request, and in turn makes an HTTP request to the host specified by the CGI param "url" and returns the HTML.

Comment: In dotNet framework, it's pretty easy to grab XHTML or any valid XML via a server-side script and search it using XPATH. The Html (non-XML compliant) variant is likely a little trickier. I've implemented similar in the past using the HtmlAgilityPack, which sort of implements XPATH expressions (it's attribute searches used to be odd, don't know if they ever fixed it).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375461/get-html-code-using-javascript-with-a-url) for how to fetch the HTML from a URL.

You can use the jQuery function [`parseHTML`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to convert a string into a bunch of DOM objects, and then [select elements](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) from those DOM objects.

If you insist on using XPath then you might want to take a look at [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.evaluate), or [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10596417/is-there-a-way-to-get-element-by-xpath-in-javascript).

Comment: My problem is, that if I use this function in jsfiddle from the link of the thread, I receive the error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.digitec.ch/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: From this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375461/get-html-code-using-javascript-with-a-url

Comment: If you can use jQuery then the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call should suffice, no? Is [digitec](https://www.digitec.ch/) the website you want to scrape?

Comment: I've tried this function: $.ajax({ url: 'http://www.digitec.ch', success: function(data) { alert(data); } }); But the error is the same. I try that in Chrome.

Comment: Quick search gives you [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68555/discussion-between-c0dev-and-jens).

Answer (score 0):

I think that [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) will help you.