# How to get given URL's page source in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get given URL's page source in Javascript.

Suppose i give 
window.open("https://www.google.co.in");
then it should go to above URL and take page source of google.com which can be save in file.
I am using JS in HTML.

Comment: This can't be done in javascript.  You need to do this on the server.

Comment: I think a better question is **why** do you want to do this? If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like you want to get the source of the page that your user is attempting access and replacing it with a copy you've pulled yourself. But **why??** This is what the browser is designed to do.

Comment: @ Smeegs how to do it using other lang with the help of JS

Comment: @esqew actually i wanted to find out all links in given page a save them in a file

Comment: window.open("https://www.google.co.in");
var sourceObj = "view-source:" + window.location.href;

Answer (score 0):

I you want a cross-domain solution (like your example for google), you can't.

See [How to get html source code from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289027/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-external-url)