# Get page source of external URL and manipulate with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl

I'd like to somehow get the page source of an external URL, and with that, be able to get the contents of an `h1` element.

For example, this is the logic:

```
 var url = "http://example.com";

 var src = // page src of url 

 // instead of document, it would use the variable src
 var headerText = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML;
 alert(headerText);
```

I know I can get stuff with curl/php, but have heard larger sites will cause server strain. I'd prefer to keep this as efficient as possible. Not really sure where to start.

Comment: Maybe [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) with jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289027/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-external-url

Answer (score 0):

This **cannot** be done, **by policy**.

In Web pages, JavaScript (and client-side scripts in general) aren't allowed to access raw external resources from a different domain, in general.

The closest you're going to get is using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) ([jQuery helps](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)) to access a resource, but you (*in general*) need to be requesting a URL under the same domain.