# Search for a value in Page via Page URL using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I have a page that has a table with ID as below

```
<table id="T1">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Qassas</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>test</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Via **Page URL** (I think I need to use something like `XMLHttpRequest`),

- How can I get an element (Table) with its ID?

  - Then check if the `qassas` value exists in a table "T1" **in this page, retrieve the values of all tds beside the cell that contains the matched value `qassas`

**P.S:** the value is located in the first column

Any help would be fully appreciated

Comment: When you say Page URL, do you mean that the page is not open yet? Is this somehow related to pages stored in any SharePoint library?

Comment: yes, the page is not open yet, it's not related to SharePoint, it's HTML page on my site!

Comment: Are you able to get the page via Javascript? i.e. the html string of the page?

Comment: can you give us this url please ?

Comment: Sure https://blog.devoworx.net/test/

Comment: can you write script on this page ?

Comment: no, I need to write a script in another page outside this site to read from this page via its URL, I did this in C# but i can't do it via JS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get html source code from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289027/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-external-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to get the **HTML** content of a page if you've not access to this page, and not written a script that return the content.

I support my answer with this Stackoverflow question: [How to get html source code from external url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289027/how-to-get-html-source-code-from-external-url)

Otherwise, if want to check if the value `Qassas` exist inside the table `T1` you need to use the jQuery selector [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), here is a simple demo:

```js
//This Script check if "Qassas" exist in the table or not
if( $('#T1 td:contains("Qassas")').length  > 0)
{
  alert("Qassas exist");
}else
{
  alert("Qassas doesn't exist");
}

//This script retrieve the values of the closest "td" tags

var tr=$('#T1 td:contains("Qassas")').parent();
var values=[];
tr.children().each(function(){
  values.push($(this).text());
});
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="T1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>Qassas</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it what about the second request of search in table for a specific value, please post it to accept the answer

Comment: just click on the check mark, that you'll find at the left side of my answer. Good Luck

Comment: No Problem, I will. but I need to check if a value exists in a table "T1" get the td values besides! I mentioned this in my question, could you help me for this?!

Comment: @M.Qassas I edited my answer to show you how to check if `Qassas` exist or not

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I just need to get the value of all td beside the cell that contains qassas instead of show alert message :) could you help!

Comment: @M.Qassas by values you mean the text 1,2,3 ... ? What do you want with these values ?

Comment: yes bro, i need when find the matched value in a specific cell get the value of other cells in the same row, I am sorry for this confusion but i already mention this in my question. Thanks again for your helpful support :)

Comment: @M.Qassas sorry for that, I reedited my answer, you can get these values :) Good luck